# Conditional stament for custom template page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

Is it possible to have a conditional if statement for a specific custom template page in wordpress?

Example:

```
 <?php if ( is_page('custom-home.php') ) { ?>

     //do this on my home page

   <?php } elseif ('custom-gallery.php') ) { ?>

      //do this on my gallery page

  <?php } else { ?>

  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`is_page_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) returns true when the specified template is being used:

```
if( is_page_template( 'custom-home.php' ) ) { 
    // do home stuff
} elseif( is_page_template( 'custom-gallery.php' ) ) {
    // do gallery stuff
}
```